# Reverse mouse zooming direction Xcode

Tags: xcode

How can I reverse the zooming of the storyboard when I press option + mouse wheel?

I know how to change it on my laptop in settings but I don't see an option for Xcode.

Thank you

Comment: You can't, as there is is no option for that in settings.

Comment: Oh waoh, that's sad, I guess I'll have to adapt. Thank you @Sulthan

Answer (score 0):

For zooming you can set double touch mouse in:
Click the Apple icon in left corner of your screen
Go to System Preferences>Mouse> set your zooming in More gestures tab